# I can't look anywhere (どこでも見ちゃだめです）？

Tags: grammar, syntax

What's the most natural way of saying "I can't look anywhere (without getting embarrassed)" Both polite and casual?

> - どこでも見ちゃだめだ (casual?)
> - どこでも見ちゃだめです
> - どこでも見てはだめ
> - どこでも見てはいけない (polite?)

Comment: `I can't look anywhere (without getting embarrassed)"` <- This means 「（照れずには）どこも見られない」, no? 「どこも｛見ちゃ/見ては｝｛だめだ/だめです/だめ/いけない｝」 would mean "You can't see" in the sense of "You are not allowed to see." (Use どこも not どこでも)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use 目のやり場がない or 目のやり場に困る though I'm not sure whether the sentences are something one is allowed to say aloud

Comment: あ～なるほろ。。そゆことね～・・

Answer (score 0):

Some of them are not so bad, but if you don't explain the cause, they pretty much all feel like you have been forbidden to look anywhere.

I would say
どこ見ても照れちゃうんだ。（casual）